# AWS CodePipeline : Get some source from CodeCommit without rebuilding everything

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I have 2 projects depending on my library 
The 2 projets (project A and B) have their own CodePipeline's Pipeline, rebuilding (thanks to aws's CodeBuild) them each time I push on CodeCommit *(If I push A, A will be rebuilt, same for B)*

**BUT**
I want to rebuild A **AND** B when I push my library and ONLY my library onto CodeCommit.

The problem I am facing is that when I'm pushing A or B, its rebuilding both A and B because the  said pipeline detects some changes

[image: Here's my Pipeline config]

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you are looking for ways to restrict Build to the repository where you have made the commit. However, this use case is not supported at this moment. How CodePipeline works with multiple sources currently is it allows multiple source actions in a single pipeline. A change/commit in either source will trigger a pipeline execution. The thing to know is that every pipeline execution will pull the latest source for both actions (not just the one with a commit that triggered the pipeline execution).

The alternate way for your use case could be to use separate CodePipelines for the repositories but there may be additional charges.

Comment: Wwhat I finally did is creating a CodePipeline for all my projects where the source is the project's code commit and the Framework's codecommit aswell.
Thank you for guiding me to the right path